# SUM() all rows after current row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this table:

```
Level Count
  1     0
  2     2
  3     1
  4     5
  5     0
```

I want to get this from a query:

```
Level Count
  1     8
  2     8
  3     6
  4     5
  5     0
```

Any ideas? 
SQL Server 2012!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL Server 2012+, you can just use a cumulative sum:

```
select level, count, sum(count) over (order by level desc) as cumecount
from t;
```